# Where is the NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 6.0.3.4 and I can't find the "NoMethodError in Ga::Districts#index":

undefined method `cases' - Did you mean?
case
class

In this line:

```
<% @district.cases.each do |case_data| %>
```

Here are my files:

**District Model**

```
class District < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :cases
  belongs_to :state
end
```

**Case Model**

```
class Case < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :diagnosis
  belongs_to :district

  scope :unconfirmed, -> { where(confirmed_at: nil) }
  scope :confirmed, -> { where.not(confirmed_at: nil) }
end
```

**District Controller**(/controllers/ga)

```
class Ga::DistrictsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :current_user_ga?

  def current_user_ga?
    return if current_user.role == 'ga'
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def index
    @district = District.includes(:cases).where(id: 1) 
    #I don't want to use a static ID, instead it should be the district_id of the current user.
  end
end
```

and the **index.html.erb** (views/ga/districts)

```
<h1>Total cases for</h1>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Gender</th>
      <th scope="col">Birthdate</th>
      <th scope="col">Place of residence</th>
      <th scope="col">Diagnosis</th>
      <th scope="col">Confirmed at</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @district.cases.each do |case_data| %>
      <tr>
          <td><%= case_data.gender %></td>
          <td><%= case_data.birthdate %></td>
          <td><%= case_data.place_of_residence %></td>
          <td><%= case_data.diagnosis.illness %></td>
          <td><%= case_data.confirmed_at %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would really appreciate any kind of input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think where returns an array of records so you have to concatenate first in your query:

```
@district = District.includes(:cases).where(id: 1).first
```

Or even easier instead of using where you can use find:

**Edit:** I made a mistake using the `find` method, this should be the correct way to fetch the district:

```
@district = District.includes(:cases).find(1)
```

Also there is not a n+1 problem to fix when fetching only one record so you can safely remove the includes part of the query:

```
@district = District.find(1)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply! The first solution worked! But what should I do, when I want to use the district_id of the current_user? Can u help me with that? I think then I have to use where(...).

Comment: Given that there is a `has_many :users` association in your District model, you can add a `belongs_to :district` association in the User model, then you can fetch the right value either using the id or the model something like:
`@district = District.includes(:cases).find(current_user.district_id)` or in a cleaner way: `@district = District.includes(:cases).find(current_user.district)`